# Angular UI-Router nested state template not rendered

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to ui-router and can't get `layout.directory.teams` or `layout.directory.people` to load their respective templates.  I expect those templates to be loaded in the `ui-view`on the `layout` state's template.

`/dashboard` works fine...the `dashboard.html` template is loaded in the `ui-view` in `content.html` template.

`/directory/teams` doesn't load the `teams.html` template.

`/directory/people` doesn't load the `people.html` template.

```
.state('layout', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "components/common/content.html"
})
.state('layout.dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: "app/features/dashboard/views/dashboard.html",
})
.state('layout.directory', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/directory"
})
.state('layout.directory.teams', {
    url: "/teams",
    controller: 'DirectoryCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'directory',
    templateUrl: "app/features/directory/views/teams.html",
})
.state('layout.directory.people', {
    url: "/people",
    controller: 'DirectoryCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'directory',
    templateUrl: "app/features/directory/views/people.html",
})
```

Comment: Add `template: "<div ui-view></div>"` to `layout.directory` state. A child state renders in the template of its parent... so, the parent must have `ui-view`

Comment: Well that was easy enough...it worked :)  If you add that as an answer I can accept it.  Is that because the child states need to inject their template into their direct parent's ui-view instead of the top level ui-view (in my case, layout)?

Comment: Yes... added as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A child state renders its template in the template of its parent where `ui-view` directive is, even if the parent is `abstract`.

So, in your case, add `ui-view` to the template of `layout.directory` state:

```
.state('layout.directory', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/directory",
    template: "<div ui-view></div>"
})
```